# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' while self joining a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe, error-handling

I have a dataframe df which is as follows.I have made this column "FN3LN4ZIP" using another larger dataframe.Now when I am self joining it,it is giving error, TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' .What could be the reason and how to solve it.
-When I am doing same for another column for bigger dataset,it is self joining easily.

```
  df:
  CustID    FN3LN4ZIP
    1   [ABY|MACL|153]
    2   [ABY|MACL|153]
    3   [AD|NBO|4103]
    4   [AY|NABO|7981]
    5   [ADE|LPK|7981]
```

Using following codes to self join:

```
df = pd.merge(df,df,on="FN3LN4ZIP",how = "inner")
```

Comment: It's not possible to merge using a column containing lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't join on `list` type, you can map your column to `string` in order to merge then map it back to the original `list` type

```
import ast
df["FN3LN4ZIP"]= df["FN3LN4ZIP"].map(str)
pd.merge(df,df,on="FN3LN4ZIP",how = "inner")
df["FN3LN4ZIP"]= df["FN3LN4ZIP"].map(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: Thanks @Yefet for the help.